# How to hide loader when there is no more page to be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

In this website that I am building https://vase.ai/blog/ , I am using a script of infinite scrolling to make several pages into one page for scrolling.

I would like to hide the loader(the spinning one) when there is no more page to be loaded. I figured that the following code might be able to help me to detect the error (`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))` and execute the hiding. However, it does not work. Am I missing something out?

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  $('loading').fadeOut()
}, true);
```

Code that I use to to load more :

```
//implementing infinite scrolling
$grid.infinitescroll({
  // Pagination element that will be hidden
  navSelector: '.pagination',

  // Next page link
  nextSelector: '.pagination a',

  // Selector of items to retrieve
  itemSelector: '.grid-blog',
},

// Function called once the elements are retrieved
function(new_elts) {
  var elts = $(new_elts).css('opacity', 0);

  elts.animate({opacity: 1});
  $grid.packery('appended', elts);

  $('.target-resize').textfill({
    maxFontPixels: 36,
    changeLineHeight:false
  })

  $grid.packery({
    itemSelector: '.grid-blog',
    gutter: 20,

  })
});
```

Comment: could you include the code you are using to load the extra pages?

Comment: @TheRickest Hi updated with the codes.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without the code that make the http calls in order to load your content. But,

1) you may have an error, and still have contents to be loaded, in that case your loader will disappear even if contents are still loading.

2) You should have something that tel your site what you have to load. 
an array of url, or anything, you can maybe use this to hide your loader when all contents has been loaded.

3) You should have somewhere a function that make httpcalls to get your content. This function should have a callback. In this callback, you should be able to catch an error, and then hide your loader.

I cannot give you more informations with the amount of code you show in your exemple.

---

edit : after looking at your code, you may try to do :

```
// Function called once the elements are retrieved
function(new_elts) {
    if(!new_elts) {
        $('loading').fadeOut();
        return;
    }
...
}
```

I don't think this is the right solution, your plugin should have a built-in function to stop calling new pages, but since I don't see the function that make the http call, or any array/iterator of URLs, it's difficult top help you.

you should check this demo to : https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/rwwoGe

Comment: @TonyNg : what is the lib you use ? is it a Jquery plugin ?

Comment: hi this is the plugin I am using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.1.0/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js

Comment: @TonyNg. Ok I still don't see what function load your pages. In this demo (https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/rwwoGe), there is an array of contents to load. Where do you specify your URL ?